# Simple command to combine an arbitrary number of values of arbitrary types into a single string

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, variadic-functions, boost-preprocessor

Consider the following code.

```
int id = 666;
stringstream stream(stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
stream << "Object " << id << " active.";
file.write(stream.str());
```

It combines all the values preceded by << in a string quite nicely. I would love to discover a shorter, easier to use version with less code duplication. Furthermore, the above code is just an example, and the command should accept arbitrary combinations of variables and strings. Ideally something like:

```
int id = 666;
WRITE("Object ", id, " active.");
```

Is this possible in C++ **in a portable way**, even with Boost.Preprocessor, inlined functions and all the bag of tricks.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific, since as it stands you should just be able to just wrap the original code in a function called `WRITE`.

Comment: Could you make your `WRITE` something like `printf` with the `...` concept?

Comment: So you just want to put an arbitrary number of different type values out to the file? You could try a variadic template.

Comment: I appologise for the very unclear question. I tried to improve it, clarifying that I need a variable number of arguments and that *it is not obligatory to use stringstream*.

Comment: A `std::stringstream` is open for reading and writing by default, there's no need to construct it with `(stringstream::in | stringstream::out)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want type-checking don't use C++, it's a statically-typed language!

If you just mean you want it to work for any type, either use a macro (*eurgh*) or use variadic templates, something like https://gitlab.com/redistd/redistd/blob/master/include/redi/printers.h which supports:

```
#include <redi/printers.h>
using redi::println;
int main()
{
  int id = 666;
  println("Object ", id, " active.");  // write arguments to stdout
}
```

The `println` function takes any number of arguments and was <strike>shamelessly stolen from</strike> inspired by some example code from [Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant).

It would be quite easy to adapt that to write to an `fstream` instead of `std::cout` e.g. by adding

```
inline
void
fprintln()
{ file << std::endl; }

template<typename T0, typename... T>
  inline
  void
  fprintln(const T0& t0, const T&... t)
  {
    print_one(file, t0);
    fprintln(t...);
  }
```

Then:

```
 fprintln("Object ", id, " active.");  // write arguments to 'file'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this without type checking using a macro:

```
//filewrite.h
#define WRITE(first, second, third) \
{\
   stringstream stream(stringstream::in | stringstream::out);\
   stream << first << second << third;\
   file.write(stream.str());\
}
```

Or, cleaner, with a template function:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
void WRITE(T1 const& first, T2 const& second, T3 const& third, fstream& file)
{
   stringstream stream(stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
   stream << first << second << third;
   file.write(stream.str());
}
```

Comment: given the title, I think the intent is do it w/o typechecking, hence not specific types in your function params

Comment: Now any way to extend it for taking unlimited number of requirements?

Comment: @MartyE you could, using varargs, but I don't have time to check for the syntax right now.

Comment: When using a macro, unlimited parameters could also be used easily if the `(x << y << z)` notation can be used in the user code.

Comment: The last two comments could very well be the two correct answers to my query. I'll check them out!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need (nor want) macros.  This is what templates were designed
for:

```
template <typename T>
void
write( std::string const& prefix, T const& value, std::string const& suffix )
{
    std::ostringstream fmt;
    fmt << prefix << value << suffix;
    file.write( fmt.str() );
}
```

On the other hand, why bother?  Why not just let the client code use the
idiomatic:

```
file << prefix << value << suffix;
```